# Nullish Coalescing Postfix Operator?

Tags: ecmascript-next

I want to increment a property value, but initialize it to 0 if it doesn't exist.

This works, but is a little clunky:

```
x = { };
let i = 0;
x[i] = (x[i]||0) + 1; // Increment by one. (If not present, init to zero.)
```

Perhaps it could be `++x[i] ??= 0`. But that is fiction, and would be limited to increment by 1.

1. Get the value V of property P of X.
2. If value is undefined or null, assign new value to P.
3. Increment P by amount N.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for<sup>1</sup>

```
x[p] ??= 0;
x[p] += n;
```

You cannot combine the two assignments into a single expression. What you can do is similar to what you've already written:

```
x[p] = (x[p] ?? 0) + n;
```

Nothing clunky about this.

<sub>1: `??=` is part of the accepted [*logical assignment* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment/) and will be part of ES2021.</sub>